# directly export to pdf from ssrs viewer in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, asp.net-mvc-5, rdl

I have ssrs report viewer url and tried directly convert to pdf :

http://someIP/Reports_Server/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReport+Folder%2fReport+Name&Parameter=parametervalue&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF

If I tried to access it in browser, it did not render to pdf, and parameter not passed.
I did something like this in mvc 5 :

```
 public ActionResult GetPdfReport()
    {
        NetworkCredential nwc = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = nwc;

        string reportURL = "http://someIP/Reports_Server/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReport+Folder%2fReport+Name&Parameter=parametervalue&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF";


        return File(client.DownloadData(reportURL), "application/pdf", "filename.pdf");
    }
```

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully got PDF report from our SSRS system via browser URL. I used next URL:

```
http://serverAddress/reportServer?/report_folder/report_name/&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rc:Toolbar=false&rc:Parameters=false&client_id=107
```

where `client_id` is report parameter.

Comment: can i have example to define report folder and report name in the url? because I do not know much about ssrs

Comment: Off course, in my case it: `/egger/slow_mover/` where egger is folder name, slow_mover - report name

Comment: I have tried many times, but it's always redirect to viewer aspx :(

Comment: this is my url : `http://IPServer/Reports_Server?/Report+ARIA/MI/MI+-+PMNInstitusi/&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rc:Toolbar=false&rc:Parameters=false&NoAktifitas=20151028000007`

Comment: Are you sure that SSRS web service URL is Reports_Server not reportServer?

Comment: I dont know much about that, this is my report server : `Reports_IDSQL2012`

Comment: You can find extra infromation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/bb630447(v=sql.120).aspx about SSRS web service configuring

Comment: Look here : "When you access a report server or Report Manager through its URL, the URL should include the host name and not the IP address. On a TCP/IP network, the IP address will resolve to a host name (or the network name of the computer). If you used the default values to configure URLs, you should be able to access the Report Server Web service using URLs that specify the computer name or localhost as the host name:

`http://<computername>/reportserver`

`http://localhost/reportserver"`

Comment: So I've tried access to web service via IP address of server and didn't have success.

Comment: I think you have redirect because url of your web service is not valid

Comment: So, your URL have to look like this: `http://Reports_IDSQL2012/reportServer?/Report+ARIA/MI/MI+-+PMN/&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rc:Toolbar=false&rc:Parameters=false&NoAktifitas=20151028000007`

Comment: Glad to hear this :)